# Mixitup plugin with drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

By default MixItUp Will apply filtering click handlers to any element with the class 'filter' like this:

```
<ul>
     <li class="filter" data-filter="dogs"> </ li>
     <li class="filter" data-filter="cats"> </ li>
     <li class="filter" data-filter="krakens"> </ li>
     <li class="filter" data-filter="dogs cats"> </ li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, elements filtered May Be Directly via javascript with the 'filter' method.

`Syntax: $ ('# Grid') mixitup ('filter', 'dogs').`

But I want my controls use  tag:

```
`<select id="cd-dropdown" name="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
<option value=""> SELECT CATEGORY </ option>
<option value="mix"> ALL </ option>
<option value="cat0"> CAT 0 </ option>
<option value="cat1"> CAT 1 </ option>
<option value="cat2"> CAT 2 </ option>
<option value="cat3"> CAT 3 </ option>
</ select>`
```

Because I'm trying to implement this jquery dropdown list found on codrop:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/

I'll put the script of this plugin for query :

```
 ;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

    'use strict';

    $.DropDown = function( options, element ) {
        this.$el = $( element );
        this._init( options );
    };

    // the options
    $.DropDown.defaults = {
        speed : 300,
        easing : 'ease',
        gutter : 0,
        // initial stack effect
        stack : true,
        // delay between each option animation
        delay : 0,
        // random angle and positions for the options
        random : false,
        // rotated [right||left||false] : the options will be rotated to thr right side or left side.
        // make sure to tune the transform origin in the stylesheet
        rotated : false,
        // effect to slide in the options. value is the margin to start with
        slidingIn : false,
        onOptionSelect : function(opt) { return false; }
    };

    $.DropDown.prototype = {

        _init : function( options ) {

            // options
            this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.DropDown.defaults, options );
            this._layout();
            this._initEvents();

        },
        _layout : function() {

            var self = this;
            this.minZIndex = 1000;
            var value = this._transformSelect();
            this.opts = this.listopts.children( 'li' );
            this.optsCount = this.opts.length;
            this.size = { width : this.dd.width(), height : this.dd.height() };

            var elName = this.$el.attr( 'name' ), elId = this.$el.attr( 'id' ),
                inputName = elName !== undefined ? elName : elId !== undefined ? elId : 'cd-dropdown-' + ( new Date() ).getTime();

            this.inputEl = $( '<input type="hidden" name="' + inputName + '" value="' + value + '"></input>' ).insertAfter( this.selectlabel );

            this.selectlabel.css( 'z-index', this.minZIndex + this.optsCount );
            this._positionOpts();
            if( Modernizr.csstransitions ) {
                setTimeout( function() { self.opts.css( 'transition', 'all ' + self.options.speed + 'ms ' + self.options.easing ); }, 25 );
            }

        },
        _transformSelect : function() {

            var optshtml = '', selectlabel = '', value = 1;
            this.$el.children( 'option' ).each( function() {

                var $this = $( this ),
                    val = isNaN( $this.attr( 'value' ) ) ? $this.attr( 'value' ) : Number( $this.attr( 'value' ) ) ,
                    classes = $this.attr( 'class' ),
                    selected = $this.attr( 'selected' ),
                    label = $this.text();

                if( val !== 1 ) {
                    optshtml += 
                        classes !== undefined ? 
                            '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span class="' + classes + '">' + label + '</span></li>' :
                            '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span>' + label + '</span></li>';
                }

                if( selected ) {
                    selectlabel = label;
                    value = val;
                }

            } );

            this.listopts = $( '<ul/>' ).append( optshtml );
            this.selectlabel = $( '<span/>' ).append( selectlabel );
            this.dd = $( '<div class="cd-dropdown"/>' ).append( this.selectlabel, this.listopts ).insertAfter( this.$el );
            this.$el.remove();

            return value;

        },
        _positionOpts : function( anim ) {

            var self = this;

            this.listopts.css( 'height', 'auto' );
            this.opts
                .each( function( i ) {
                    $( this ).css( {
                        zIndex : self.minZIndex + self.optsCount - 1 - i,
                        top : self.options.slidingIn ? ( i + 1 ) * ( self.size.height + self.options.gutter ) : 0,
                        left : 0,
                        marginLeft : self.options.slidingIn ? i % 2 === 0 ? self.options.slidingIn : - self.options.slidingIn : 0,
                        opacity : self.options.slidingIn ? 0 : 1,
                        transform : 'none'
                    } );
                } );

            if( !this.options.slidingIn ) {
                this.opts
                    .eq( this.optsCount - 1 )
                    .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 9 : 0, left : this.options.stack ? 4 : 0, width : this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 8 : this.size.width, transform : 'none' } )
                    .end()
                    .eq( this.optsCount - 2 )
                    .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 6 : 0, left : this.options.stack ? 2 : 0, width : this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 4 : this.size.width, transform : 'none' } )
                    .end()
                    .eq( this.optsCount - 3 )
                    .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 3 : 0, left : 0, transform : 'none' } );
            }

        },
        _initEvents : function() {

            var self = this;

            this.selectlabel.on( 'mousedown.dropdown', function( event ) {
                self.opened ? self.close() : self.open();
                return false;

            } );

            this.opts.on( 'click.dropdown', function() {
                if( self.opened ) {
                    var opt = $( this );
                    self.options.onOptionSelect( opt );
                    self.inputEl.val( opt.data( 'value' ) );
                    self.selectlabel.html( opt.html() );
                    self.close();
                }
            } );

        },
        open : function() {
            var self = this;
            this.dd.toggleClass( 'cd-active' );
            this.listopts.css( 'height', ( this.optsCount + 1 ) * ( this.size.height + this.options.gutter ) );
            this.opts.each( function( i ) {

                $( this ).css( {
                    opacity : 1,
                    top : self.options.rotated ? self.size.height + self.options.gutter : ( i + 1 ) * ( self.size.height + self.options.gutter ),
                    left : self.options.random ? Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 - 5 ) : 0,
                    width : self.size.width,
                    marginLeft : 0,
                    transform : self.options.random ?
                        'rotate(' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 - 5 ) + 'deg)' :
                        self.options.rotated ?
                            self.options.rotated === 'right' ?
                                'rotate(-' + ( i * 5 ) + 'deg)' :
                                'rotate(' + ( i * 5 ) + 'deg)'
                            : 'none',
                    transitionDelay : self.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ? self.options.slidingIn ? ( i * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : ( ( self.optsCount - 1 - i ) * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : 0
                } );

            } );
            this.opened = true;

        },
        close : function() {

            var self = this;
            this.dd.toggleClass( 'cd-active' );
            if( this.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ) {
                this.opts.each( function( i ) {
                    $( this ).css( { 'transition-delay' : self.options.slidingIn ? ( ( self.optsCount - 1 - i ) * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : ( i * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' } );
                } );
            }
            this._positionOpts( true );
            this.opened = false;

        }

    }

    $.fn.dropdown = function( options ) {
        var instance = $.data( this, 'dropdown' );
        if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
            this.each(function() {
                instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
            });
        }
        else {
            this.each(function() {
                instance ? instance._init() : instance = $.data( this, 'dropdown', new $.DropDown( options, this ) );
            });
        }
        return instance;
    };

    } )( jQuery, window );
```

I tested tricks but I do get nothing conclusive!

Here I found someone who has implemented the fancyselect and mixitup script, but I can not do the same with the dropdown menu.
I give you the link!
https://github.com/hasinhayder/ResponsiveGalleryWithFiltering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem was here and I solved the issue.

1- You should notice that the dropdown plugin you are using is removing the select and option tags and replace them with a ul-li and a hidden input filed the `name` attribute of the `input` is the same of the `name` or `id` of the `select` tag.

so if you have : 
`<select id="cd-dropdown" name="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">`

you get an input like this: 
`<input type="hidden" name="cd-dropdown" value=""></input>`

2- what you want is to change the `mixitup` filter whenever the `input` value is changed like so:

```
$("[name=cd-dropdown]").on("change",function(){

        item = $(this).val();
        //console.log(item);

        $('#pub-grid').mixitup('filter',item);
    });
```

3- the above wont work, because the input field is `hidden` and has no listener of `change` that is, no one is listening to the hidden field to detect if it is changed or not. So, you should trigger the event whenever you change the value of the input field.

In order to do this, open up the dropdown plugin and go to line 147 and add your trigger:

oroginal price of code:

```
this.opts.on( 'click.dropdown', function() {
    if( self.opened ) {
        var opt = $( this );
        self.options.onOptionSelect( opt );
        self.inputEl.val( opt.data( 'value' ) );    
        self.selectlabel.html( opt.html() );
        self.close();
    }
} );
```

add trigger for `change`:

```
this.opts.on( 'click.dropdown', function() {
    if( self.opened ) {
        var opt = $( this );
        self.options.onOptionSelect( opt );
        self.inputEl.val( opt.data( 'value' ) ).trigger('change');
        self.selectlabel.html( opt.html() );
        self.close();
    }
} );
```

thats it, your final code would look like this :

```
$('#Grid').mixitup();
$( '#cd-dropdown' ).dropdown( {
    gutter : 4
} );

$("[name=cd-dropdown]").on("change",function(){
    item = $(this).val();   
    $('#Grid').mixitup('filter',item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but for new visitors:

You can do this without changing the plugin code.

The codrops dropdown plugin gives the option to pass the option value, e.g.

```
onOptionSelect : function( opt ) {
   window.location = opt.data( 'value' );
}
```

In here you can call the mixitUp plugin and pass the filter or sort data, so your total code would look like:

```
$( '#cd-dropdown' ).dropdown( {
 gutter : 4,
 onOptionSelect : function( opt ) {
    jQuery('#Grid').mixItUp('filter', opt.data( 'value' ));
 }
});
```